# dbt run operation with args that has environment variable

Tags: macros, dbt

How do I run a dbt `run-operation` with arguments that have environment variables. For eg:

```
dbt run-operation my_macros --args '{"model":"abc", "colour":"$COLOUR_NAME"}'
```

It seems that `$COLOUR_NAME` is not getting the value of the variables as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing it in command line, you can reference the environment variable as a default value directly in your macro.

```
{% macro my_macros(model, colour=env_var('COLOUR_NAME')) %}
...
{% endmacro %}
```

This gives you the option to either use the environment variable value or to override it in the command line with the `--args` option you have above.